# Cómo hacer push desde git bash sin hacer deletions

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash

Cuando hago cambios en mi repositorio local solo cambio el nombre de algunas carpetas. Luego al hacer push me encuentro con que borré algunas cosas y en otras solo moví el directorio.

No entiendo por qué me aparece esto ya no estoy tocando nada más a parte del nombre de la carpeta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el mismo commit me encuentro con esto, se supone que al cambiar solo el nombre de la carpeta todos los casos deberían ser como en esta imagen (File Moved):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué debería hacer para que solo me mueva los archivos sin hacerr deletions?

Comment: eres el unico que hace cambios en ese repositorio? supongo que primero haces un merge de remoto y luego haces el commit y el push verdad? Lo digo porque si tienes a otro usuario que trabaja en el mismo repositorio puede ser el que ha hecho los cambios...

Comment: Hay varias personas que utilizan el mismo repo pero nadie toca esa sección específica que estoy modificando, yo simplemente clono el repositorio, cambio los nombres de las carpetas y hago commit, luego push, en todo ese proceso nadie ha intervenido